# how to make ajax call on same page ajax request send and get in same page

Tags: ajax

here is ajax code i'm implement this code
i want to call ajax request same page where i want to get the request mean same page send request and get request

```
 function data(status)
{    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"main.php",
      data: "status="+ status,
      success:function(data)
      {

      } }); });
```

i'm try this code but have problem in ajax call same html  page show header footer also result
how to call on self page where is ajax code how it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success callback, do the necessary DOM update.

"data" will contain the actual response text from thte page main.php.

Your html should look like something like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src=[jquery JS file]"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
      function data(status)
        {    $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:"main.php",
              data: "status="+ status,
              success:function(data)
              {
                $("#mydiv").html(data);
              } 
               }); 
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: i try as you but not solve my problem have html page  call

Comment: What is exactly the problem? What is the behavior you expect and what is the behavior you get?

Comment: i want to make autocomplete search

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
url:'main.php',

mtype:'post',//use mtype as 'get' for get reuest,

contentType:'application/json',

async:true, // for asynchronous calls

sucess:function(data)
{

},

error:function(error)

{

}

});
```

Comment: i try this code but have same problem in out put have html page

Comment: then use an iframe like this <iframe id='myFrame'></iframe>append the output to that iframe to its src using javascript